# Странности Jquery

Tags: jquery

Приведен код:

```
$.each(data.res, function(i, val) {
                        str=+'<option value="'+val.id+'">'+val.name+'</option>';
                    });
                    $('#city').prop('disabled', false).append(str);
```

В итоге в список помещается такая ерунда:

```
   <select name="city" id="city">
    NaN377406"&gt;Солсбери</select>
```

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Попробуй использовать другие кавычки

Comment: Присмотритесь к этой строке:

>    str=+'<option value="'+val.id+'">'+val.name+'</option>';

Вы, очевидно, имели в виду `str += '<option .....`, но и-за опечатки у вас конкатенируется число `NaN`, строка `val.id`, строка `">` (а экранированный знак "больше" выглядит как `&gt;`) и `val.name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот так например надо

```
$('#city').prop('disabled', false).append($(str));
```

Но лучше делать append в цикле в этом.

```
var $city=$('#city');
$.each(data.res, function(i, val) {        
    $('<option>').val(val.id).text(val.name).appendTo($city);
});
```

(это немного медленнее, но код выглядит чище, кроме того это позволяет вам собрать 
созданные элементы для дальнейшего использования)

```
var $city=$('#city'),$cityOptions=$();
$.each(data.res, function(i, val) {        
    $cityOptions.add($('<option>').val(val.id).text(val.name).appendTo($city));
});
```

или так

```
var $city=$('#city'),$cityOptions={};
$.each(data.res, function(i, val) {        
    $cityOptions[val.name]=$('<option>').val(val.id).text(val.name).appendTo($city);
});
```